# Embed TrueType fonts in existing PDF

Tags: pdf, printing, fonts

I know Acrobat won't do it because of the licensing restrictions, etc.

Does anyone know any program that will just embed True Type fonts anyway in an existing PDF (or print with embedded fonts to a new PDF, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

To expound mark's answer:

The sample [EmbedFontPostFacto.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=288) ([EmbedFontPostFacto.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter16&ex=EmbedFontPostFacto)) from chapter 16 of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) shows how you can embed a given True Type font in an existing PDF.

Be aware, though, that certain assumptions are made here, it's just an example after all. When generalizing the code for generic PDFs and fonts, the font dictionary should be checked more thoroughly and embedding the font file can require slightly different entries to be changed. In that case let [the specification ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (especially chapter 9 *Text*) be your guide.

Comment: I was kind of hoping for a program already existing rather than writing one myself, but if it comes to that I will. I have made some progress though by using a program called Embed to change the embed flag on some fonts. Now one of them is being embedded, so just one more to go.

Answer (score -2):

I believe Itext allows you to manipulate the fonts in a PDF file