# Embed non-embedded fonts in PDF with IText

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, itext, itextpdf

So I have the following problem. I receive a `PDF` file which contains a set of fonts. These fonts are not embedded into the file. Here is a simple example:

[image: non embedded font]

I would like to embed these fonts inside the `PDF`, so they're self-contained and always available. But things don't seem that simple. I'm using [`IText`](http://itextpdf.com/) to do my `PDF` processing.

I have read and tried the following questions/answers:

- [how-to-create-pdf-with-font-information-and-embed-actual-font-when-merging-them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979200/how-to-create-pdf-with-font-information-and-embed-actual-font-when-merging-them)
- [embed-truetype-fonts-in-existing-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513720/embed-truetype-fonts-in-existing-pdf)
- [embed-font-into-pdf-file-by-using-itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775008/embed-font-into-pdf-file-by-using-itext)
- [how-to-check-that-all-used-fonts-are-embedded-in-pdf-with-java-itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646130/how-to-check-that-all-used-fonts-are-embedded-in-pdf-with-java-itext)
- Chapter `16.1.4 Replacing a font` of the book `iText in Action - 2nd Edition`
- ...

But what had gotten me closest was the following example: [`EmbedFontPostFacto.java`](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-16#607-embedfontpostfacto.java) (which comes from the book). I was able to embed the `Arial` font when providing the `Arial.ttf` file.

[image: embedded font]

But with this, like with other examples, I need the source file of the font in order to embed it. In my case, I don't have the source file. But I might have them on the system however. So I'd like to query my available fonts on the system and see if it corresponds to the given font.

Something of the likes as

```
GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
java.awt.Font[] fonts = e.getAllFonts();
for(java.awt.Font f : fonts){
    System.out.println(f.getFontName());
}
```

But I cannot transform the given `java.awt.Font` into a `RandomAccessFile` or a `byte[]` to be used in order to embed the font file itself. Is there another way for embedding fonts into a `PDF`, without having the source file of the font itself?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows `C:\Windows\Fonts` or such contain all font files, and in the explorer shows also font names. So a manual search is feasible.

In java, you have `GraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames()` and `Font.getFamilyName()` to check for a name from the PDF like "Arial MT."

However a getter for the file is missing from Font.

So list all files of the font directory, and load each file consecutively as Font.

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, ttfFile);
ge.registerFont(font); // If you want to load the font.

if (pdfFontName.startsWith(font.getFamilyName()) {
    System.out.printf("%s - %s / %s%n", ttfFile.getName(), font.getFamilyName(),
            font.getName());
}
```