# iTextSharp embed subset fonts in existing PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, itext

We use an old reporting software to create PDFs, but it is unable to embed the used fonts in the file.

Now I am trying to use iTextSharp to embed all (non-embedded) fonts in an existing PDF based on these examples [EmbedFontPostFacto](https://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter16/EmbedFontPostFacto.cs#l41),  [ListUsedFonts](https://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter16/ListUsedFonts.cs) and other information from [other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023057/embed-non-embedded-fonts-in-pdf-with-itext/37024208#37024208).

Like in the first example I create a fontfile for each font and then add it to the font object (PdfDictionary) or rather to the font descriptor.

```
// the font file
byte[] fontfile = null;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(
    fontFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    fontfile = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(fontfile, 0, (int)fs.Length);
}
// create a new stream for the font file
PdfStream stream = new PdfStream(fontfile);
stream.FlateCompress();
stream.Put(PdfName.LENGTH1, new PdfNumber(fontfile.Length));


PdfDictionary desc = font.GetAsDict(PdfName.FONTDESCRIPTOR);
PdfIndirectObject objref = stamper.Writer.AddToBody(stream);
desc.Put(PdfName.FONTFILE2, objref.IndirectReference);
```

This (mostly) works, but since this embeds the entire font and not a subset, the files can get very big.

So I am wondering if there is a way to embed the fonts only as a subset retroactively, either with iTextSharp or any other way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That task requires an in-depth analysis of every usage of that font in your PDF to determine the required glyphs. While iText(Sharp) does not contain a single method for that task, you can use it as framework to implement such an analysis in. I reckon, though, that a generic implementation might well go beyond the format of a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: @mkl Thats what I feared. But thank you for your answer. If anyone has other suggestions how to achieve this it would be appreciated.